# Solutions to $y' = y + f(x)$ satisfying $y(0)=0$ and boundedness.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

> "Given that $f$ is a continuous positive real function, is there a solution function $y$ which is bounded on $\mathbb R$?"

It seems the DE is linear with integrating factor $e^{-x}$, so we have $$y=e^x(\int e^{-x}f(x)dx + c)$$The condition $y(0)=0$ implies $$\int f(0)dx + c= 0$$Therefore that last integral is a constant (specifically $-c$), which I can only see happening when $f(0)=0$ and we have solved for $c$ for that specific condtition.

Problem: 
When is , $$y=e^x(\int e^{-x}f(x)dx)$$ bounded? Using a constant $f$, the $e$'s cancel each other out. So, is "for all $f(x)\equiv K>0$, where $K$ is a real number" a good answer?

Comment: In the words of a wise person: "Write well, otherwise you end up not understanding what you're writing". The particular solution is $e^x\int_0^x e^{-t}f(t)\,dt$, therefore all that nonsense about $\int f(0)\,dx$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you mind sharing how you arrived at that? Note I am literally 2 days into the study of DEs.

Comment: You see, If i had an answer key I wouldn't be asking if my solution makes sense (or if it is a solution at all), would I? "Writing it correctly"... how, where, WHAT? Be a little constructive.

Comment: In the first line you suppose that *f* is positive. So I don't think you got the correct answer.

Comment: You're right, edited, thanks.

Comment: You should use definite integrals to write down the solutions. Your solution is not correct and there is no bounded solution even when  $f$ is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

When $f$ is a constant $K$ the solution is $K(e^{x}-1)$. This is not bounded unless $K=0$.

The correct solution of the DE is $y=e^{x}\int_0^{x} e^{-t} f(t)dt$.

Let us show that this is never bounded (unless positive means non-negative in which case the solution is bounded iff $f\equiv 0$).

There exists an interval $(a,b)$ and a  number $r>0$ such that  $f(x) >r$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. We get $y(x) >e^{x} \int_a^{b} e^{-t}rdt=r(e^{x-a}-e^{x-b})$ for all $x >b$. Hence $y \to \infty$ as $ x \to \infty$.

Comment: Is my solution wrong? Does the downvoter have a bounded solution for the IVP?

Comment: I did not downvote. Your point is correct, but the specific estimate $y(x)>e^x\int_0^x e^{-t}r\,dt$ is unwarranted at best, since $f(x)>r$ is not meant to hold eventually. From the fact that $f(x)>r$ for all $x\in (a,b)$ you can prove that $y(x)\ge e^x\int_a^b e^{-t}f(t)\,dt>r(e^{-a}-e^{-b})e^x$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thank you very much. I intended to integrate from  $a$ to $b$. I guess I hurried up a bit while typing the answer.